# Operating system not found after downloading skin pack

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems

My brother has downloaded a executable file from [Skin Pack](http://skinpacks.com/index.php) — I believe it was the Mountain Lion IO6 skin pack. He's using an Acer Aspire 553G.

And now his operating system won't start (Windows 7).

It gets to the BIOS and then goes to load up the OS but the screen goes blank and it just goes back to the BIOS over and over again. He decided to play with the bootup settings and tried different options and got the error message "Operating System not found."

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Have some questions to ask.
1. During boot, do you see if the system detects the operating system properly, and tries to boot up and fails?
2. Do you see any error messages? 
3. Does pressing F8 key bring up the boot options?

Answer (score 0):

Right after POST have him hit F8 until he gets into the boot menu and try the "Repair Your Computer" option.

Comment: This won't work as the BIOS cannot find the operating system to begin with.

Comment: Good point, throw the Windows 7 disk in the drive and boot to the System Recovery options.  Try the Startup Repair from there.

Comment: windows 7 came with his laptop, he has no disk

Comment: Can he borrow one?

Answer (score 0):

The first option would be to try and open System Restore from bootup, normally, if you can get to the Windows startup repair, cancel it before it starts trying to repair and click on "Explore additional options" then click on "System Restore"

If that does not work, you may want to do a complete system reset, each PC manufacturer has its own reset key combo.
I think for you it is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

Once there, you should have the option to keep all of the user files, meaning you will loose any installed programs and program data.